# How to add cancel button while clicking the Edit link in View?

Tags: views, nodes

I created a content type and a view; when I click the edit link shown in the view, it redirects to the filled content type page, which contains only the *Save*, *Preview*, and  *Delete* buttons. I need to have a *Cancel* button too.

How do I add the *Cancel* button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [Content type extras module](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_type_extras)

- label on manage field forms Add a 'Cancel' button to node edit forms
- Ability to set node title visibility when viewing node Ability to
- hide title of front page (takes precedence over content type setting)
- Ability to add form submission buttons to top of 'Manage fields'

Or you could use the [more buttons module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mb)

> MB provides a additional Create new action.
>
> This action can used as tab in addition to the node View or node Edit
>   tab. This action can used as action link on the node edit forms.

MB allows to use own values for:

> Cancel button,
>   Save and continue button, Save and create new button
>   Create new tab